# Библиотека для конвертации pdf в картинку

Tags: c#, wpf, поиск-библиотек

Посоветуйте пожалуйста простую библиотеку для конвертации pdf в картинку. Цель - получить страницы pdf-документа, конверировать в картинку и затем вставить в ObservableCollection

Comment: что то сами прбовали?

Comment: Пробовал многое, но все очень медленно работает. Но только что нашел хорошее решение на Win10 API https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs

Answer (score 0):

Хорошее и простое решение на основе Win10 API [здесь](https://blogs.u2u.be/lander/post/2018/01/23/Creating-a-PDF-Viewer-in-WPF-using-Windows-10-APIs).